# Use events even if just an action parameter would be sufficient?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

In my scenario, I have a class that will do some work for me every now and then and occasionally will react with some action to it. What the action actually is will be provided from the outside. I think it's important to mention, that there will be only *one* instance from the outside telling this class what has to be done.

I've implemented something like this:

```
public class DelegatePublisher
{
    private Action<byte[], int, int> onCompleted;

    public DelegatePublisher(Action<byte[], int, int> onCompleted)
    {
        this.onCompleted = onCompleted;
    }

    public void Invoke(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        onCompleted.Invoke(buffer, index, count);
    }
}
```

This can be used later as simple as:

```
public class Example
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var byAction = new DelegatePublisher(onDelegate);
    }

    private void onDelegate(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Once `Invoke` will be called the action will be called. (I left out all that `null` checking on purpose for the sake of this minimal example)

This works as expected and I am happy with that solution. However, people keep telling me that I should use `Events`. I told them that I just need a *single* `Action` to be invoked, and the code does it perfectly fine. After a long discussion, the code now looks like this:

```
public class EventPublisher
{
    public EventHandler<EventPublisherEventArgs> OnCompleted;

    public void Invoke(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        var handler = OnCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new EventPublisherEventArgs(buffer, index, count));
        }
    }
}
```

And of course the `EventArgs`:

```
public class EventPublisherEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public byte[] Buffer
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public EventPublisherEventArgs(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        Buffer = buffer;
        Index = index;
        Count = count;
    }
}
```

My ... well, "calling" code now looks like this:

```
public class Example
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var byEvent = new EventPublisher();
        byEvent.OnCompleted += onEvent;
    }

    private void onEvent(object sender, EventPublisherEventArgs e)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Is there actually any benefit in doing it as an `Event`? Or the other way around: Is there something wrong with the way using an `Action`?

All I can tell by using `Events` is that I need more code, have an extra layer of abstraction, could potentially connect multiple (not needed) callbacks and need an extra class just to hold three parameters. The only good thing I see is that I am following a common pattern. However, I have seen lots of code with passing an action as parameter, even in the BCL, which could probably be solved with events as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there actually any benefit in doing it as an Event?

Although *highly opinionated*, ill try and shed my point of view.

I don't see any straight forward benefit. It usually depends on what you need. Events are merely wrappers around delegates, they add another level of abstraction (as you said).

Must you use them? no, i see nothing wrong with your *working code example*. Don't conform to using certain patterns because "people think they're better". Follow them because you've looked and see an obvious benefit in using them. In this particular case, i don't see any added value.